# same package name in different apk

Tags: android

Is it possible to define different classes of the same package in different apk ?
By example having

```
    package org.company;
    public class A { ... }
```

in an Android project
and

```
    package org.company;
    public class B { ... }
```

in another Android project

Would it be a good thing to do ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is entirely possible.
Each APK runs in its own virtual machine, so there is no problem or overlap.

The only thing that must be uniquely named is the package name defined in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

Answer (score -1):

No problem at all.  But, you have to sign both APK with same key. Otherwise, the latter app wont install.

Comment: Surely that's nonsense, otherwise you'd never be able to bundle common third-party classes and libraries in your APK (e.g. the AdMob SDK).

Comment: @Christopher: Thrid partly libraries are already signed. Please Google with "signature level permission" and read. You will understand how we can use third party already signed libraries in our apk.

Comment: Third-party libraries, which in Android are distributed either as source (a library project), or a JAR, are not already signed. Permissions and code signing have nothing to do with this question.

Comment: You seem to not getting my point here. You can have multiple source packages in a project. But, in AndroidMenifest, you have a package="my.package.xyz" under manifest tag. Which is the main package of your application. Now, you can have multiple apk's having same package="my.package.xyz". In that case, you have to sign both with same key. You can use hundreds of other packages in source codes of other packages. It does not matter. The package which you specify in manifest is also shown in the "Manager Applications" settings page.

Comment: So it seems your answer doesn't answer the actual question, by conflating APK package IDs with Java package names. It's also 100% wrong to state that you can have multiple APKs installed on a device with the same manifest package ID.